# Tomcat 7 as a HTTP file server

Tags: java, tomcat

Using Tomcat 7 as a HTTP file server return the following error on high load (after burst of many requests):

> Jul 02, 2017 1:42:42 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder writeResponse
>   SEVERE: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:711)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2549)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2538)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException

What are the best practices for avoiding this error? Where does it come from? I have tried to use NIO mode and still got this error.

Answer (score 1):

The `ClientAbortException`seems to indicate that a client aported its connection.